# What's a linked window?

Tags: vba

I'm trying to familiarize myself with Visual Basic Add-In Model. I don't understand what `LinkedWindowFrame` and `LinkedWindows` properties mean. Could someone kindly explain a little bit? Thank you!

**Edit:** There's a definition as follows:

> **linked window**
>   A window that is joined to another window other than the main window.

But I don't think I've ever seen anything as described... :(

Answer (score 1):

From [VS6.0 Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443976(VS.60).aspx)

> Linked window frames contain all
>   windows that can be linked or docked.
>   This includes all windows except code
>   windows, designers, the Object Browser
>   window, and the Search and Replace
>   window.window.

So a `LinkedWindow` is any sort of tool window that can belong to a `LinkedWindowFrame`.  Windows belonging to the same `LinkedWindowFrame` are docked together.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that. But I still don't understand what it says. Maybe I need a screenshot :(

Comment: When multiple toolbox windows are docked together in the same frame, you get a tabbed layout (think tabbed browser, though in VS2010 these tabs are along the bottom of the window instead of the top).  The frames themselves can normally be docked to an MDI parent window or free floating (in VS2010 they can now free float outside of the MDI window host).